# Quickblox Room Chat Android

Tags: android, xmpp, quickblox

i am working on a Messenger app in Android. I am using quickblox API for the chat.
in Group chat, I am sending message to the group but i never received any message in group chat. form the logs it seems that messages being sent but it never receives at my end.
here are  logs:

```
 10-13 15:37:31.436: D/SMACK(5629): 03:37:31 PM SENT (1130884280): <message id="283JG-7" to="14353_test456@muc.chat.quickblox.com" type="groupchat"><body>hdjfjr</body></message>


10-13 15:37:31.826: D/SMACK(5629): 03:37:31 PM RCV  (1130884280): <message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat" to="1692168-14353@chat.quickblox.com/Smack" from="14353_test456@muc.chat.quickblox.com/1692168" id="283JG-7"><body>hdjfjr</body></message>
```

It never comes in override method processMessage of ChatMessageListener. Please let me know where is the problem.